# 'RuntimeJob' object has no attribute 'queue_position'

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices, qiskit-runtime

I was trying to run a QAOA job using the below script:

```
job = provider.runtime.run(
    program_id=program_id,
    options=options,
    inputs=runtime_inputs,
)

from qiskit.tools import job_monitor
job_monitor(job)
```

But I'm getting the below error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [24], line 73
     65 #Now, we run the program using the provider.
     67 job = provider.runtime.run(
     68     program_id=program_id,
     69     options=options,
     70     inputs=runtime_inputs,
     71 )
---> 73 job_monitor(job)
     75 #Job Status: job has successfully run
     77 print(f"Job id: {job.job_id()}")

File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/tools/monitor/job_monitor.py:89, in job_monitor(job, interval, quiet, output, line_discipline)
     86 else:
     87     _interval_set = True
---> 89 _text_checker(
     90     job, interval, _interval_set, quiet=quiet, output=output, line_discipline=line_discipline
     91 )

File ~/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/tools/monitor/job_monitor.py:49, in _text_checker(job, interval, _interval_set, quiet, output, line_discipline)
     46 msg = status.value
     48 if status.name == "QUEUED":
---> 49     msg += " (%s)" % job.queue_position()
     50     if job.queue_position() is None:
     51         interval = 2

AttributeError: 'RuntimeJob' object has no attribute 'queue_position'
```

In the IBM portal, it is showing my job is queued, but my code is failing at job_monitor(job)

[image]

Can anyone suggest what can be done for this issue?

Comment: Seems that `provider.runtime.run()` returns a `RuntimeJob`, while it's the class `IBMQJob` that has the `queue_position()` method.  So apparently `job_monitor()` doesn't work correctly on jobs started this way.  :-(

Comment: I was following the documentation https://qiskit.org/documentation/optimization/tutorials/12_qaoa_runtime.html so probably that should have worked fine, since in the docs it was used in the same way.

Comment: Yeah. Feels like a bug. Just explaining why it’s failing.

Comment: It is a reported bug: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/7865